# statics not found for post request on express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi guys i am facing a problem regarding express.static() functions while working with express js i have defined statics for my each routes using

```
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/views/includes')));
app.use('/post/add', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/views/includes')));
```

which works fine for get requests but when i submit a post request from a form it just don't load the statics i defined above any solution to that?

this is my post method which going to render add_post page after processing the form data i am using `express-handlebars` as my view engine

```
// process add post
app.post('/post/add',function (req,res,next) {

        res.render('add_post');

});
```

thanks any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`express.static` only responds to GET (and HEAD) requests. The [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html) doesn't mention this, but you can see the code [here](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js#L73). This is by design since it's intended just to serve resources to GET requests. It's generally just used for loading static html, css, js, and images.

POST requests are for creating resources, so it doesn't make much sense to serve a static file to a POST request. It would be a rare use-case.

The more usual way of implementing what you want is exactly what you've ended up doing: Defining your own handler using `app.post`. I'm afraid that's probably the best way forward.

Comment: hey thanks for your response actually i am trying to load css and javascript files which are responsible for handling front end design all the lay out gets disturbed when i submit a form using post method.
is these any example you would like to recommend how can i load static resources using app.post handler?

Comment: if there is any other solution please guide me to that thanks in advance :)

Comment: You shouldn't be loading your css and javascript through POST requests. When you submit a form, that should make a POST request to a URL. From there, you probably want to send an html file through `res.sendFile` or `res.render`. That html file will make GET requests to the static css and js resources. Here's a quick example I threw together to show how I'd usually do this: https://github.com/tfogo/routing-example

Comment: Hopefully that's a useful example of how to structure this.